# How to Renter to texture in MonoGame?

Tags: c#, android, monogame

So.. With my attempt so far, this is what happens, the game is not stretching:

[image]
And here's the way I'm doing it:

I have this variable declared.

```
RenderTarget2D renderTarget;
```

In my game1 constructor, I have this: I tried the actual screen resolution here too, same thing.

```
graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 96;
graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 160;
```

In my Initialize, I have this:

```
renderTarget = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth,
            GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight, false,
            GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferFormat, DepthFormat.Depth24);
```

I have this function here:

```
protected void DrawSceneToTexture(RenderTarget2D renderTarget)
    {
        // Set the render target
        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(renderTarget);

        GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = new DepthStencilState() { DepthBufferEnable = true };

        // Draw the scene
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.PointClamp,
            DepthStencilState.None, RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise);
        switch (gameState)
        {
            case GameStates.Menu: { menuState.Draw(spriteBatch); break; }
            case GameStates.Playing: { playingState.Draw(spriteBatch); break; }
            case GameStates.GameOver: { gameOverState.Draw(spriteBatch); break; }
        }
        spriteBatch.End();

        // Drop the render target
        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
    }
```

And my draw method looks like this:

```
DrawSceneToTexture(renderTarget);

        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend,
            SamplerState.LinearClamp, DepthStencilState.Default,
            RasterizerState.CullNone);

        spriteBatch.Draw(renderTarget, new Rectangle(0, 0, actualScreenWidth, actualScreenHeight), Color.White);

        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [PreferredBackBufferWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphicsdevicemanager.preferredbackbufferwidth.aspx) it says:

> If you request a back-buffer resolution that is not supported by the output device, the XNA Framework automatically selects the highest resolution supported by the output device. For example, if a graphics back buffer with a resolution of 1920×1080 (1080p or 1080i) is created and displayed on a device with 480i resolution, the back buffer automatically is resized to 480i.

So, I suspect what's happening is that when you setup your RenderTarget2D the value coming out of GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth is not 96.

Try setting the render target width and hieght directly and see if that solves your problem.

```
renderTarget = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, 96, 160, false,
        GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferFormat, DepthFormat.Depth24);
```

If you are just trying to scale your rendering to fit the screen you might make your life simpler by removing all of the DrawSceneToTexture stuff and just set the scale in the [SpriteBatch.Begin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433701.aspx) method, something like this:

```
var scaleX = (float)actualScreenHeight / (float)virtualHeight;
var scaleY = (float)actualScreenWidth / (float)virtualWidth;
var transformMatrix = Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(scaleX, scaleY, 1));

spriteBatch.Begin (sortMode, blendState, samplerState, depthStencilState, rasterizerState, effect, transformMatrix);
```

Comment: Thanks, setting the render target width and height directly worked, turns out I was close!